# Hugging Face Chat UI .ENV.CI Parameters

Tags: mongodb, artificial-intelligence, huggingface

I am trying to follow the instructions for hugging face's chat ui: https://github.com/huggingface/chat-ui

I've pulled the repo and have a MongoDB account.

In the .env.ci file I set it to the following

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv://myUsername_myPassword@aicluster.boctvbq.mongodb.net/
HF_TOKEN=myHuggingFaceToken
```

I copied my MongoDB URL from MongoDB Compass. When I run npm install
npm run dev from the terminal I get this

```
3:36:26 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/lib/server/database.ts:
|- Error: Please specify the MONGODB_URL environment variable inside .env.local. Set it to mongodb://localhost:27017 if you are running MongoDB locally, or to a MongoDB Atlas free instance for example.
    at /Users/username/AI/chat-ui/src/lib/server/database.ts:14:8
    at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/username/AI/chat-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:56052:9)

3:36:26 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/hooks.server.ts: failed to import "/src/lib/server/database.ts"
|- Error: Please specify the MONGODB_URL environment variable inside .env.local. Set it to mongodb://localhost:27017 if you are running MongoDB locally, or to a MongoDB Atlas free instance for example.
    at /Users/username/AI/chat-ui/src/lib/server/database.ts:14:8
    at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/username/AI/chat-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:56052:9)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with MongoDb?

My Chat UI app is not able to run locally.